# Fail to connetc AWS greengrass

Tags: docker, yocto, mosquitto, aws-iot-greengrass

My OS is Yocto Rocko on i.MX6Q.
I used docker v17.06 to load three greengrass image version 1.7.1, 1.8.1 and 1.9.2.

I followed the README.md in each package to setup up and install step by step.
All images were failed to connect AWS greengrass group I created.

The following are logs about the error, I think the reason is MQTT setting has something wrong. I google mosquitto.conf about greengrass, and I couldn't find any solution.

Here is my mosquitto info.

```
root@imx6qsabresd:/etc/mosquitto# mosquitto -h
mosquitto version 1.4.14 (build date 2019-06-26 15:24:46+0800)

mosquitto is an MQTT v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.
```

Could anyone tell me how to setting mosquitto.conf for greengrass?
Or is the root cause another one?

**greengrass v1.7.1 log**

```
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.214Z][INFO]-===========================================
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.214Z][INFO]-Greengrass Root: /greengrass
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.214Z][INFO]-Greengrass Write Directory: /greengrass/ggc
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.214Z][INFO]-Group File Directory: /greengrass/ggc/deployment/group
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.214Z][INFO]-Default Lambda UID: 122 GID: 121
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.214Z][INFO]-===========================================
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.223Z][INFO]-The current core is using the AWS IoT certificates with fingerprint: 5da1e3eb3aefdc0c3adf0607284ea00debba05af257ba42b96c9c211f441f5bf
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.224Z][WARN]-worker process info: /greengrass/ggc/packages/1.7.1/var/worker/processes
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.225Z][WARN]-worker process info: /greengrass/ggc/packages/1.7.1/var/worker/processes
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.234Z][INFO]-Reloading registry
[2019-07-01T02:49:18.236Z][INFO]-The current core is using the AWS IoT certificates with fingerprint: 5da1e3eb3aefdc0c3adf0607284ea00debba05af257ba42b96c9c211f441f5bf
[2019-07-01T02:49:23.291Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:49:28.297Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:49:34.303Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:49:39.309Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:49:45.315Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:49:53.321Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:50:20.327Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout
[2019-07-01T02:50:45.363Z][WARN]-Attempt to establish MQTT connection with a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883 failed and will be retried: Network Error : dial tcp 52.196.224.122:8883: i/o timeout
```

**greengrass v1.8.1 log**

```
[2019-07-01T03:28:02.096Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: ibGG, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:28:17.102Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:28:17.102Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:28:33.097Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:28:33.097Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: ibGG, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:29:07.098Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: qPeP, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:29:22.159Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 13.231.29.48:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:29:22.159Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:29:38.099Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:29:38.099Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: qPeP, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:30:00.1Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: tQVE, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:30:15.105Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.81.83:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:30:15.105Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:30:31.101Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:30:31.101Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: tQVE, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:30:34.102Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: bbZJ, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:30:49.134Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:30:49.134Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:31:05.103Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:31:05.103Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: bbZJ, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:31:49.103Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: QZad, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:32:04.144Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:32:04.144Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:32:20.105Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:32:20.105Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: QZad, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:32:54.105Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: RhWa, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:33:09.14Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.81.83:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:33:09.14Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:33:25.107Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:33:25.107Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: RhWa, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:33:52.107Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: RKLh, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:34:07.113Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 13.231.29.48:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:34:07.113Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:34:23.108Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:34:23.108Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: RKLh, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:35:22.109Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: cJQX, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:35:37.186Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.224.122:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:35:37.186Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:35:53.11Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:35:53.11Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: cJQX, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:36:25.111Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: tPkl, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:36:40.176Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.224.122:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:36:40.176Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:36:56.112Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-07-01T03:36:56.112Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried: attemptId: tPkl, clientId: zohan_Core: operation timed out
[2019-07-01T03:37:22.112Z][INFO]-MQTT connection attempt: attemptId: RJbR, clientId: zohan_Core
[2019-07-01T03:37:37.118Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 54.178.150.112:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-07-01T03:37:37.118Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-07-01T03:37:53.113Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open
```

**greengrass v1.9.2 log**

```
ogot@imx6qsabresd:/usr/aws/aws-greengrass-docker-1.9.2/log/system# cat runtime.lo
[2019-06-28T03:12:10.073Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:12:10.073Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:12:10.073Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:12:10.073Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "RHeO", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:12:11.074Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "LcQc", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:12:11.074Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:12:11.074Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:12:11.074Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:12:26.128Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.224.122:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:12:26.128Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-===========================================
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-Greengrass Version: 1.9.2-RC4
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-Greengrass Root: /greengrass
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-Greengrass Write Directory: /greengrass/ggc
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-Group File Directory: /greengrass/ggc/deployment/group
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-Default Lambda UID: 122
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][INFO]-Default Lambda GID: 121
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.813Z][DEBUG]-Go version: go1.10.3
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.814Z][DEBUG]-CoreThing Connection Config:
{
        "Region": "ap-northeast-1",
        "ThingArn": "arn:aws:iot:ap-northeast-1:268205529033:thing/zohan_Core",
        "IoTMQTTEndpoint": "a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883",
        "IoTHTTPEndpoint": "a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8443",
        "GGMQTTEndpoint": "greengrass-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883",
        "GGHTTPEndpoint": "greengrass-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8443",
        "GGMQTTKeepAlive": 600,
        "GGMQTTMaxConnectionRetryInterval": 60,
        "GGMQTTConnectTimeout": 30,
        "GGMQTTPingTimeout": 30,
        "GGHTTPTimeout": 60,
        "FIPSMode": false,
        "CoreClientId": ""
}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.814Z][DEBUG]-System Config:
{
        "tmpDirectory": "",
        "shadowSyncTimeout": 0
}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.814Z][DEBUG]-Runtime Config:
{
        "maxWorkItemCount": 1024,
        "schedulingFrequency": 1000,
        "maxConcurrentLimit": 25,
        "lruSize": 25,
        "cgroup": {
                "useSystemd": true,
                "mountPoint": null
        },
        "postStartHealthCheckTimeout": 60000,
        "allowFunctionsToRunAsRoot": false,
        "onSystemComponentsFailure": 0
}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.814Z][INFO]-===========================================
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.814Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/5da1e3eb3a.cert.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.814Z][INFO]-The current core is using the AWS IoT certificates with fingerprint.   {"fingerprint": "5da1e3eb3aefdc0c3adf0607284ea00debba05af257ba42b96c9c211f441f5bf"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.815Z][INFO]-Will persist worker process info.      {"dir": "/greengrass/ggc/packages/1.9.2/var/worker/processes"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.816Z][INFO]-Will persist worker process info.      {"dir": "/greengrass/ggc/packages/1.9.2/var/worker/processes"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.817Z][DEBUG]-loading subscriptions {"trie": "map[]"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.819Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/root.ca.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.823Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested key load [file:///greengrass/certs/5da1e3eb3a.private.key] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.823Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/5da1e3eb3a.cert.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.826Z][INFO]-No proxy URL found.
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.827Z][DEBUG]-Reloading function registry.
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.828Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/5da1e3eb3a.cert.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.828Z][INFO]-The current core is using the AWS IoT certificates with fingerprint.   {"fingerprint": "5da1e3eb3aefdc0c3adf0607284ea00debba05af257ba42b96c9c211f441f5bf"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.833Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/root.ca.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.836Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested key load [file:///greengrass/certs/5da1e3eb3a.private.key] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.837Z][DEBUG]-[3]Requested certificate load [file:///greengrass/certs/5da1e3eb3a.cert.pem] with error: [<nil>]
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.84Z][INFO]-Started Deployment Agent to listen for updates.
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.841Z][INFO]-Connecting with MQTT.  {"endpoint": "a3ha96wpso16t3-ats.iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.841Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "sbXW", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.841Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.841Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:06:24.841Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:46:09.317Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.81.83:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:46:09.317Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:46:25.26Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.26Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client      {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.26Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "sbXW", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "nTLn", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:46:25.261Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:46:40.266Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 13.231.29.48:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:46:40.266Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:46:56.262Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:46:56.262Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:46:56.262Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:46:56.262Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:46:56.262Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:46:56.263Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "nTLn", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:46:57.263Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "qkJH", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:46:57.263Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:46:57.264Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:46:57.264Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:47:12.307Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 54.178.150.112:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:47:12.308Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:47:28.264Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.264Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.264Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "qkJH", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "DTsS", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:47:28.265Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:47:43.27Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.224.122:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:47:43.27Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:47:59.266Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:47:59.266Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:47:59.266Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:47:59.266Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:47:59.266Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:47:59.266Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "DTsS", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:48:02.267Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "EkzV", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:48:02.267Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:48:02.267Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:48:02.267Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:48:17.325Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:48:17.325Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:48:33.268Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:48:33.268Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:48:33.268Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:48:33.268Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:48:33.268Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:48:33.268Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "EkzV", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:48:45.269Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "bRjP", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:48:45.269Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:48:45.269Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:48:45.269Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:49:00.275Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:49:00.275Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:49:16.27Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.27Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client      {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.27Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.27Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:49:16.27Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.27Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.     {"attemptId": "bRjP", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.271Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "HyAU", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.271Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.271Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:49:16.271Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:49:31.333Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.192.233.211:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:49:31.333Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:49:47.271Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:49:47.271Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:49:47.271Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:49:47.272Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:49:47.272Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:49:47.272Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "HyAU", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:50:14.272Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "suqf", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:50:14.273Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:50:14.273Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:50:14.273Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:50:29.278Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:50:29.278Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:50:45.274Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:50:45.274Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:50:45.274Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:50:45.274Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:50:45.274Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:50:45.274Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "suqf", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:51:29.275Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "YfqT", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:51:29.275Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:51:29.275Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:51:29.275Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:51:44.314Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.199.190.37:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:51:44.315Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:52:00.276Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:52:00.276Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:52:00.276Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:52:00.276Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:52:00.276Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:52:00.276Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "YfqT", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:52:56.277Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "DIBy", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:52:56.277Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:52:56.277Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:52:56.277Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:53:11.338Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 52.196.81.83:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:53:11.338Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker

[2019-06-28T03:53:27.278Z][DEBUG]-Marking connection request as invalid
[2019-06-28T03:53:27.278Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": true}
[2019-06-28T03:53:27.278Z][DEBUG]-Disconnecting client
[2019-06-28T03:53:27.278Z][WARN]-MQTT[store]    Trying to close memory store, but not open

[2019-06-28T03:53:27.278Z][DEBUG]-Releasing lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:53:27.278Z][WARN]-MQTT connection attempt failed and will be retried.    {"attemptId": "DIBy", "clientId": "zohan_Core", "errorString": "operation timed out"}
[2019-06-28T03:53:38.279Z][DEBUG]-MQTT connection attempt.      {"attemptId": "RAeH", "clientId": "zohan_Core"}
[2019-06-28T03:53:38.279Z][DEBUG]-New MQTT connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:53:38.279Z][DEBUG]-Acquired lock for connection attempt
[2019-06-28T03:53:38.279Z][DEBUG]-Disconnect client     {"force": false}
[2019-06-28T03:53:53.285Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   dial tcp 13.231.29.48:8883: i/o timeout

[2019-06-28T03:53:53.285Z][WARN]-MQTT[client]   Failed to connect to a broker
```

Comment: I'm having this error right now. Could you solve it and if yes share how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS MQTT on port 443 which is usually available. To use this port http header value "application protocol name" needs to be set to “x-amzn-mqtt-ca”. Please read more on this here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/mqtt-with-tls-client-authentication-on-port-443-why-it-is-useful-and-how-it-works/

Answer (score 0):

Greengrass has its own MQTT broker.

If you want to connect MQTT clients to AWS Greengrass, you have to follow their
directions at

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html

We have FAILED to connect mosquitto client to Greengrass as documented at

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=305032&tstart=0

(which you will likely only see if you login to AWS).

Comment: You're right, that's not an MQTT issue. I tried your solutions and other ways, and I found the root cause: port 8883 is prohibited by MIS. Now, v1.9.2 is worked, but v1.8.1 and v1.7.1 are failed. So I decided to use v1.9.2 and gave up to try v1.7.1 & v1.8.1.